# Spring Boot- Autowiring interface implemented by different beans

Tags: spring, list, spring-boot, interface, autowired

I have multiple beans with @Component implementing a generic interface.

I have a class where I use methods from these beans. Instead of autowiring each bean separately, I was figuring out of autowiring the interface as a list.

But how do I call the methods of different beans when I just autowire the interface.

```
public interface Generic {
}

@Component
public class A implements Generic{
.....
public void test{
}

}

@Component
public class B implements Generic{
.....
public void read{}

}


@component class C {

@Autowired
List <Generic> mylist;  // type of list is Generic
```

Now I need to access read from B and test from A

Comment: The only way to use `read()` and `test()` method is to cast them to relevant class (`A` or `B`) and then invoke the method.

Comment: @Saranya_R Do you have an order in which 'read()' and 'test()' should be called ?

Answer (score 1):

With your new question you **CAN** do it like this way but *I think it's better to use 2 seperate lists* instead of the instanceOf.

```
public interface Generic { }

public interface GenericTestable extends Generic { 
    void test()
}

public interface GenericReader extends Generic { 
    void read()
}

@Component
public class A implements GenericTestable { 
   public void test() { }
}

@Component
public class B implements GenericReader { 
   public void read() { } 
}

@Component
public class C {

   private final List<Generic> genericItems;

   @Autowired
   public C(List<Generic> genericItems) {
       this.genericItems = genericItems;
   }

   public void callThem() {
       this.genericItems.forEach(this::callMethodOnSpecificType);
   }

   private void callMethodOnSpecificType(Generic genericItem) {
       if (genericItem instanceof GenericTestable) {
           ((GenericTestable) genericItem).test();
       } else if (genericItem instanceof GenericReader) {
           ((GenericReader) genericItem).read();
       }
   }
}
```

But I think that something like this is a better approach. Cleaner and faster code. Remove the Generic interface and use only the 2 separate interfaces.

```
public class BetterC {

    private final List<GenericTestable> genericTestables;
    private final List<GenericReader> genericReaders;

    @Autowired
    public BetterC(List<GenericTestable> genericTestables, List<GenericReader> genericReaders) {
        this.genericTestables = genericTestables;
        this.genericReaders = genericReaders;
    }

    public void callTestables() {
        this.genericTestables.forEach(GenericTestable::test);
    }

    public void callReaders() {
        this.genericReaders.forEach(GenericReader::read);
    }
}
```

Comment: I adopted the first approach. But in both approaches how do I use A.test and B.read in class C.

Comment: I see that you changed your original code and add `read()` and `write()` to the specific classes. It depends on the rest of your code if this is the best strategy. The interfaces are now a bit strange because the question is if they are of the same type.

Comment: The only way to use it now and call `read()` and `test()` is to iterate over the list and check with instanceOf for the specific type and then cast it to the specific type and call `read()` or `test()`. That's not a good idea. If you only have these 2 objects it's better to remove the interface and autowire them each on its own. If you have multiple of them you can choose to use 2 different interfaces let say `GenericReader` and `GenericWriter `and use 2 lists (`List<GenericReader> readers` and `List<GenericWriter> writers`)

Comment: Actually I added the interface just to implement autowire in a simple way. I have about 10 classes basically they are 10 different reports each implementing a generate method in different ways with different arguments. So I cannot have generate method in the interface. I thought of implementing the interface in each report class and then autowire the interface. But I need to call the methods from report classes for each report to be generated. I dont understand if that can be actually achieved so I moved to Application context and got the beans from context.

Comment: Example changed in line with the new/modified question.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Generic interface to route the call ?

From the java-doc api : [Ordered](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html)

> Ordered is an interface that can be implemented by objects that should
>   be orderable, for example in a Collection. The actual order can be
>   interpreted as prioritization, with the first object (with the lowest
>   order value) having the highest priority.

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;

public interface Generic extends Ordered {
    void call();
}
----
@Component
public class A implements Generic {

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void call() {
        test();
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Call test()");
    }
}
----
@Component
public class B implements Generic {

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void call() {
        read();
    }

    public void read() {
        System.out.println("call read()");
    }
}
----
@Component
public class C {

    List<Generic> list;

    public C(List<Generic> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        for(Generic g: list) {
            g.call();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this in your implementation

```
@Component
@Qualifer("a")
public class A implements Generic{ ..... public void test(){ }}

@Component
@Qualifer("b")
public class B implements Generic{ ..... public void read(){ }}

@component 
public class C {

    @Autowired
    Generic a;

    @Autowired
    Generic b;

    ... call respective methods

}
```

Comment: I do not want to keeo using @Autowired for all beans. Just autowiring the interface should do that. But I do not know how to call my methods.